# How to use AlchemyAPI with java?

Tags: java, maven, alchemyapi

I want to use AlchemyAPI in my Java project. 
I am using Maven for my dependency management. I am planning to use [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.uima/AlchemyAPIAnnotator/2.3.1) maven repository.
So, I want to know if the have any documentation is available.
Also, I will like to know how to use my API key. They have given it [here](http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/sdks/). 
But, as I am using Maven, I don't know what to do..?

Thank You in Advance..!

Comment: All I could find in terms of documentation is a little code example here -> https://code.google.com/p/alchemy-annotator/source/browse/trunk/iks-uima-demo   and    http://gate.ac.uk/gate/plugins/AlchemyAPI/src/com/alchemyapi/api/AlchemyAPI.java . If any of these are what you are looking for then tell me so I can put them up as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the official java libary is not mavenized - I believe, You could try this https://github.com/likethecolor/Alchemy-API/blob/master/README.md